# Spring session jdbc - How to add multiple HttpSessionIdResolver for a single application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-jdbc, spring-session

I have a problem in injecting multiple HttpSessionIdResolver for a single spring application.

For normal web application I would like to use CookieHttpSessionIdResolver
For Rest API I would go for HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver and Rest API url will be like "/api/**"

Internally spring sets a bean and uses that bean for all request(In this case HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver 
and my web stopped working because i dont set X-Auth-Token header for every request) but i would like to override it.
Could any one please help me.

Thank you.

```
@EnableJdbcHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 3600)
public class SessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDatabase")
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}

@Bean(value = "httpSessionIdResolver")
public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
    return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken(); 
}

@Bean(value = "cookieHttpSessionIdResolver")
public HttpSessionIdResolver cookieHttpSessionIdResolver() {
    return new CookieHttpSessionIdResolver();
}
}
```

Comment: 1. This isn't an `@Configuration` class. 2. you are using Spring BOot which auto-configures this, so ditch this class and just define 2 beans.

Comment: Internally EnableJdbcHttpSession annotation uses @Configuration

Comment: It doesn't. Nor do you need it if you just would use the proper mechanism for using spring-session with spring-boot. You are working around it.

Answer (score -1):

I overridden spring session to enable both cookie and header based session.
Now it's working fine.

Currently I'm checking for URL that contains /api/* and if it contains i'm using header based other wise cookie based session.

Comment: Could you please post the sample implementation?